# Achieving 500MB+ WebSQL iOS safari storage

Tags: javascript, ios, ios7, safari, web-sql

Does anyone have any data on the supposed "no-limit" WebSQL feature of a homescreen web app in iOS7?

Using [storage abuser](http://demo.agektmr.com/storage/) I have been able to store persistantly 450MB on my homescreen Safari web app until it continually crashes on startup. I noticed it doesn't ask the user for permission too which is great.

Anyone else had any other experiences with it yet? Curious to see what the true upper limit is.

Comment: You don't happen to use phonegap? This is just a browser accesible application? If phonegap/cordova you could always opt for the SQLLite plugin

Comment: Originally I thought I would have to go down the phonegap route to get around the 50MB limit, but this recent discovery is leading me more towards a homescreen app if it works reliably in production