# IOS Mobile Safari Html5 WebSql Data storage Limit

Tags: mobile-safari, web-sql

From other posts it seems there is a limit of 50Mb for Data storage on mobile Safari (IOS 10)
[Example SO post on Limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921048/limit-of-localstorage-on-iphone)
[Questions about achieving more under ios7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25425016/achieving-500mb-websql-ios-safari-storage)   remain unanswered.

**Is there a way to store more tha 50 Mb with a HTML5/Javascript app on mobile safari?**
or are we forced to look at Cordova style solutions ?
Is there a non Native app solution ?

**EDIT: We ended up building a Hybrid App.**

RANT:
In my view Apple is deliberately sabotaging SAFARI so people have to build native apps so Apple can take a % of sales.  If people can build good HTML5 apps then there is no need for a store APP and Apple is just a platform.
Greed will come back to bite you Apple.